# Reply back to a response

Tags: php, curl, response, mdm

I need to reply back to a response received.

How should I reply using the response?

I want to reply to a response received in my MDM System. The device contacts the server and delivers status as idle. Now I need to send a xml command directly to the device.

Comment: Resolved.. Just need to return it.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't push from PHP Webserver to HTTPClient, the HTTPClient must contact you first (Unless you write a sockets module, then php could be the wrong language) - Only said it as I'm not certain what your trying to achieve.

Anyway straight to the point - Once the device contacts the server, and gives the status 'idle', you can just immediately write out an echo response

```
if(isset($_POST['status']) && $_POST['status'] == 'idle') {
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><root>
<data>blablabla</data>
    </root>';
}
```

etc. Depends on how the devices actually contacts the server, is it sending a post command? Is it actually connecting as a HTTPClient or just a direct TCP/IP? Is there anymore info you can provide?